# I have problems while pushing values into queue

Tags: java, simulation

I am writing a one queue-system simulation program in java. In my program, I want to push a value into my queue and my program reads that line but queue size returns 0.

This part is pushing a value into the queue

```
EL nextEvent = new EL(clock);
q.push(nextEvent); // pushing the first incoming customer in queue
cust--; // still waiting for other customers
```

Here is my queue

```
public class queue {

EL[] q;
int head;
int tail;
int rear;
int cap = 10000;
int count;

public queue(int cap) {
    super();
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
    this.q = new EL[cap];
}


public void push(EL item){
    if (!isFull()){
        rear = (rear + 1) % cap;
        q[rear] = item;
        count++;
    }
}

public EL pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    int tmp = head;
    head = (head + 1) % cap;
    return q[tmp];
}

// measures the size of a queue
public double size(){return count;}
public boolean isEmpty(){return (size() == 0);} // checks if queue is empty or not
public boolean isFull(){return (size() == cap);} // checks if queue is full or not
}
```

And here is my EL class

```
public class EL {
double atmQEnterTime;
double atmQLeaveTime;
double atmLeaveTime;

public EL(double atmQEnterTime){
    this.atmQEnterTime = atmQEnterTime;
    atmQLeaveTime = 0;
    atmLeaveTime = 0;
}
public double getTotTime() {return atmLeaveTime - atmQEnterTime;}
public double getQWaitTime() {return atmQLeaveTime - atmQEnterTime;}
}
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't push any value into my queue.

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) can't you just return the length of 'q'? 
2) why is the method returning a double when in reality it's an int?

Comment: I think you should remove one between `tail` and `rear`. Also, you never decrement `count` in `pop()`, so `size()` will always return a wrong value in case `pop()` is called at least once -> you can/should detect that in a unit test

Comment: I can see a few bugs, but nothing that would cause `push()` to not push anything.  If you want help debugging, you need to provide a proper MCVE; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  A couple more hints: 1) write some unit tests for your class, and 2) read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why are you building your own rather than using one of the library classes, such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html ?